# Что общего между стеком и кучей?

Tags: память, структуры-данных, стек

Иногда встречаю в переводах на русский иностранной литературы, что стек и кучу иногда используют как синонимы. Вот этого я не понимаю. Ведь кучей называется динамическая память, в которой можно размещать разные типы данных (new, malloc). А стек ведь совсем по другому устроен. Стек это как стопка, что наверх положили, то и берем. Или когда они отождествляют стек и кучу, то они имеют ввиду кучу как структуру данных? Разъясните, а то как-то мутно и непонятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Про стек и без того понятно. А про "кучу", как структуру данных - хорошо [описано в вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0_(%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)). С том числе и про различие терминов кучи - как структуры, и кучи - как способа динамического распределения памяти.

Comment: Вот в том-то и вопрос получается, а можно ли использовать кучу как структуру данных для того чтобы сделать стек? Кто реализует стек, операционная система или это аппаратная возможность?

Comment: Если говорить о динамическом выделении памяти, то стек - это непрерывная область памяти, на которую ссылаются соответствующие регистры (для архитектуры x86 - это пара ss:sp, ну и "расширенные" версии для больших разрядностей). Процессор, выполняя команды "push","pop", изменяет эти регистры. Таки образом стек или "растет" или "уменьшается". Используя ассемблерные вставки, можно самостоятельно двигать стек - но КРАЙНЕ важно к моменту выхода из процедуры вернуть стек в исходное состояние.

Comment: Если говорить о динамическом выделении памяти, то куча - это область памяти, где есть возможность размещать данные. Но каких-либо аппаратных инструментов управления кучей нет. Максимум, что контролирует аппаратура и операционная система - это выход за пределы допустимых адресов. Посему, где и как реализовывать логические структуры - все на откупе разработчика.

Answer (score 1):

Куча не только динамическая память. Это (heap) еще и пирамида - структура, на которой осенована пирамидальная сортировка, например.

Правда, использовать пирамиду как стек вряд ли получится. Разве как очередь с приоритетами.